# I am trying to understand a section of a mathematical journal about the trajectory of shuttlecock

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, arithmetic

I am trying to derive equation 13) of the article below. The article is about deriving the function for the trajectory of shuttlecock, and I am currently focusing on the first case of the article when the drag force is linear.

The article says that equation 13) has been derived by adding equation 8) and 12) in the article but I am not sure how the combination of the two equations 8),12) have resulted in 13).

Could anyone help me out? I am really lost in the calculations.

https://www.jssm.org/volume08/iss4/cap/jssm-08-657.pdf

Comment: “Combining” doesn’t mean “adding” there. They mean that they have used the definition of $y$ in 8 and $x$ in 12 to rewrite $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Thank you. That clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

> The article says that equation (13) has been derived by adding equation (8) and (12) in the article but I am not sure how the combination of the two equations (8), (12) have resulted in (13).

Let's look at the equations $(8)$ and $(12)$:

$$y(t) = \frac{v_t}{g}(v_t + v_{yi})\left(1 - e^{-\frac{gt}{v_t}}\right) - v_tt \tag 8$$

$$x = \frac{v_tv_{xi}}{g}\left(1 - e^{-\frac{gt}{v_t}}\right) \tag {12}$$

Rearrange the equation $(12)$:
$$\frac{gx}{v_{xi}} = v_t\left(1 - e^{-\frac{gt}{v_t}}\right) \tag {1}$$

Rearrange the equation $(8)$:

$$gy(t) = \frac{gx}{v_{xi}}v_t^2\left(1 - e^{-\frac{gt}{v_t}}\right) + v_tv_{yi}\left(1 - e^{-\frac{gt}{v_t}}\right) - gv_tt \tag 2$$

Substitute the equation $(1)$ to the equations $(2)$:

$$gy(t) = \frac{gx}{v_{xi}}v_t + \frac{gx}{v_{xi}}v_{yi} - gv_tt \tag 3$$

Rearrange the equation $(3)$ after dividing by $g$ both sides:

$$y(t) = x\left(\frac{v_t + v_{yi}}{v_{xi}}\right) - v_tt \tag 4$$

Now, from the equation $(1)$:
$$e^{-\frac{gt}{v_t}} = 1 - \frac{gx}{v_{xi}v_t} = \frac{v_{xi}v_t - gx}{v_{xi}v_t}  \tag {5}$$
Take the recipocal of the equation $(5)$:
$$e^{\frac{gt}{v_t}} = \frac{v_{xi}v_t}{v_{xi}v_t - gx} \ \Rightarrow \ \frac{gt}{v_t} = \ln \left(\frac{v_{xi}v_t}{v_{xi}v_t - gx}\right) \\ \therefore \ v_tt = \frac{v_t^2}{g} \ln \left(\frac{v_{xi}v_t}{v_{xi}v_t - gx}\right)  \tag {6}$$

Substitute $v_tt$ in the equation $(6)$ in the equation $(4)$:

$$y(t) = x\left(\frac{v_t + v_{yi}}{v_{xi}}\right) - \frac{v_t^2}{g} \ln \left(\frac{v_{xi}v_t}{v_{xi}v_t - gx}\right) \tag {13}$$